# `Exit do` escapes two while loops in nested loops at the same time

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I came across an interesting issue whilst testing my `ms-Access` Database this morning. I tried comparing every value in one `recordset` (`RsOuter`) with another `recordset` (`RsInner`). I made it in such a way that, if the matching `record` is found, it escapes the `RsInner` loop using `Exit do`. This is because once the matching record is found, no need to iterate over the rest of the records.

```
Do while not RsOuter.EOF      
       Do While Not RsInner.EOF
            If MatchFound Then
              'do Something
               Exit do ' this escapes both while loops, instead of one
            End If

            RsInner.MoveNext
        Loop
       RsInner.MoveFirst
       RsOuter.MoveNext
Loop
```

Is there a way to make it exit only one of the loops (in this case the `RsInner` only)?

Comment: The line "RsOuter" all by itself is a bug - it don't make sense and the command RsOuter all by it self likely should not even compile. You want to do a debug-compile and fix syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken that `Exit Do` breaks out of both levels in nested Do Loops. Consider the following:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Do While i < 2
        Do While j < 2
            Debug.Print "In inner loop"
            If True Then Exit Do
            j = j + 1
            Debug.Print "This shouldn't be printed"
        Loop
        Debug.Print "In outer loop"
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Debug.Print "Out of the loops"
End Sub
```

The output is:

```
In inner loop
In outer loop
In inner loop
In outer loop
Out of the loops
```

If what you said is true, "In outer loop" shouldn't print. Something else is going on with your code. Sounds like you are exiting the inner loop with the outer loop condition False

Comment: figured it out, my select statement who choosing only a certain range of dates whilst it was supposed to choose everything ah! thanks!